# Change name of view using caliburn.micro wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, view, header, caliburn.micro

in the header of my view the text is : 
BImporter.ViewModels.MainViewModel

how i can change it in (for example : MAIN) ? ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can derive your view model from `Screen` or one of the conductor types and set the `DisplayName` property.

```
public class MyViewModel : Screen
{
    protected override void OnInitialize()
    {
        this.DisplayName = "My Name";
    }
}
```